# difference between local and class variable in java by using if and else statements

Tags: java

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 10;
        int j;

        if(i == 10) {
            j = 20;
        }  else if (i == 20) {
            j = 30;
        }
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

output: `Compilation Error.Variable j might not have been initialized.`

Why is it so?

Comment: If your code is readable, people are more likely to read it.

Comment: both your block are conditional , if and else-if . thus, there is not quarantee that any value will get assigned to j. And for method level variables, explicit values assignment is required.

Comment: The error means that in some case, j could not have a value (which is true is I is not 20 nor 10). You should declare `int j = 0;` or put a `else` statement that puts a value for `j`

Comment: you can't use local variable without intialising it. so when I is not 10 or 20. it won't be intialised. but you try to print it. because of it you are getting exception

Answer (score 1):

When you use `if-else-if` without `else`, it is possible that non of the conditions will be `true`, and therefore no statement that initializes `j` will be executed, so the compiler tells you that it might not be initialized by the time you access it with the statement `System.out.println(j);`.

This can be avoided by adding an `else` clause:

```
if (I==10) {
    j = 20;
} else if (I==20) {
    j = 30;
} else {
    j = 0;
}
```

BTW, your title mentions class variables, but you have none in your question body. Unlike local variables, instance and class variables have a default value, and therefore you don't have to initialize them before accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is giving an error because even though you have assigned a value to variable `j` in `if` and `else if` block, there is one scenario in which value of `j` might not have any value(initialize) and that is the `else` condition. That is the reason why the compiler is complaining about the error. Add an `else` block to your code and initialize `j` in that. Something like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int I = 10;
    int j; // j=0; If you do this, then also, the error should go away and no need for else block
    if (I == 10) {
        j = 20;
    } else if (I == 20) {
        j = 30;
    } else {
        j = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(j);
}
```